# Using LIKE on datatable

Tags: asp.net, regex, datatable, full-text-search

I am performing a Search operation on a datatable. By using `LIKE` clause on datatable. But its not working perfectly. I am searching on a single column like this.

```
    string expression;
    expression = table.Columns[2].ColumnName.ToString() + " Like" + "'%H%'";
    DataRow[] foundRows;
    foundRows = table.Select(expression);       
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataRow dr in foundRows)
    {
        dt.ImportRow(dr);            
    }
```

Later binding that datatable `dt` to a gridview. But `table.Select(expression)` is not returning the exact rows. It returns rows which does not contains search criteria.

Can I use regex on `dt`? How can I use them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the entire problem, but I think you're missing a space after the like string: `" Like "`

Comment: I have checked the space after `LIKE` it was ok. What I was getting is for eg: a column contains records like david,sam, chris, john. It should return the records chris and john. But it was returning those including david and sam